# Html Templating in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am going to make an application in asp.net mvc4. In my application we will show some input fields based on the user's selected country.

So how to do this thing:

1- By making html helper

2- By making Seperate view for every country

Or

Please suggest if there is any other better solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your question about templates and shared code? Or is it about creating a basic view for input boxes?

Comment: My question is simple I want to show input fields based on user's selected country . Now what is the efficient way to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the input fields are quite different for each country you could make a partial for them. Also you could group commonly repeated inputs in other partials in order to be reused more easily between countries.

Comment: but in this case , don't you think we will have a bunch of views . Which could create problem in maintenance ?

Comment: Whether you maintain a bunch of views or a bunch of C# code it's pretty opinionated. Personally when it comes to HTML, I prefer to maintain views because that's what they are designed for. Use helpers only for very small HTML snippets of code. When it gets complex, views are preferred. Also web designers can more easily read HTML rather than C# when it comes to applying CSS and stuff.